# Как сделать такой вывод изображений?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть несколько изображений, все примерно одинакового размера.
Я хочу вывести эти изображения на странице в таком стиле.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал просто сделать

```
imga img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Но тогда они получаются все одинакового размера.
Наверное тут не обойтись одним css.
Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: можете сразу идти на https://github.com/kombai/freewall .... кроссбраузерный `jquery` плагин для изображений в виде кирпичиков.......... либо искать запрос в стиле `javascript photo brick` который выдаст http://masonry.desandro.com/ , http://callmecavs.com/bricks.js/ и много других плагинов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно же одним `imga img { width: 50%;}` не обойтись. Тут нужен и *css* и *js*.

Я предлагаю вам взглянуть на **[Freewall](https://github.com/kombai/freewall)**.

Это кроссбраузерный responsive `Jquery` плагин, который поможет вам создать много различного типа макетов сеток: гибкий макет, макет для фото, вложенные макеты, metro стиль, как у *pinterest* и прочие виды. Там используется `CSS3`  анимация.
Данный плагин - хорошее решение для динамического создания макета сетки как для десктопа, так и для мобильных версий и версий типа tablet.

**[домашняя страница плагина](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/)**

---

Если он не устроит, то в поиске по запросу [`javascript photo brick`](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20photo%20brick) вы сможете, я думаю, найти что-то еще подходящее для вас, например

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://callmecavs.com/bricks.js/

и многое другое.

Comment: Пиар разрешён? Больше похоже на рекламу продукта, чем ответ по теме.

Comment: @Other я что, менеджер по-вашему?)) Если у вас есть более подходящий вариант написания ответа или же свой - прошу, предлагайте :)

Comment: Я не против, просто очень уж похоже на пиар-пост.

Comment: @Other извините, я не хотел)