# Какой алгоритм используется для отображения нескольких фото в виде мозаики?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения

Например, как в ВК при загрузке фотографий. Речь идет о таком отображении:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
Возможно, для вывода изображения используется алгоритм TreeMap. Но не ясно, как задавать "веса" изображениям.

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: @nick_n_a, как вк разбивает фото в такую плитку?

Comment: не знаю как вконтакте........но http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552884/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я знаю о этой библиотеке, но она довольно большая, вычленить алгоритм из такого исходника довольно проблематично.

Comment: Выглядит как Задача об упаковке в контейнеры - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: @Kromster это только в случае если есть условие сохранить оригинальные пропорции фотографий. В случае же с ВК часто показываются обрезанные версии, например, квадрат вместо прямоугольника. В таком случае просто делаешь несколько паттернов под разное количество фотографий, а потом подгоняешь фотографии под заданные рамки. Собственно и в иллюстрации к вопросу некоторые фотографии тоже обрезаны.

Comment: @andreycha, я не думаю, что там какой то паттерн для заполнения используется. добавляя разные фотки всегда получаются разные "плитки".

Comment: @andreycha сейчас специально сделал два поста по 8 фотографий. Группировка разная, абсолютно. Ни как не могу понять алгоритм.

Comment: Можно также применить стиль Masonry. Почитайте про Masonry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Алгоритм с сохранением порядка следования картинок.**

1. Определяем количество строк как sqrt( сумма отношений сторон всех картинок / отношение сторон блока ), где отношение сторон определяется как ширина делённая на высоту.
2. Определяем *высоту строки* как высоту блока делённую на число строк.
3. Определяем общую длину всех картинок масштабированных к высоте строки.
4. Заполняем строки так чтобы ширина строки была максимально приближена к ширине оставшихся картинок делённой на количество оставшихся строк.
5. Перераспределяем высоты строк. Для этого для каждой строки считаем новую высоту так, чтобы ширина строки стала равной ширине блока. разности между новыми и старыми высотами строк суммируем отдельно по переполненным и недозаполненным строкам. В зависимости от того какая разность больше пропорционально уменьшаем изменения высот в одной из этих групп, чтобы эти суммы сравнялись. (Галочка в примере отменяет последнее выравнивание, что позволяет сохранить соотношения сторон картинок, но нарушает высоту блока).
6. Для строк у которых осталось свободное пространство (до ширины блока) масштабируем картинки так, чтобы занять всю ширину блока, после чего обрезаем их по высоте с центрированием по вертикали.
7. В строках, где нет свободного пространства масштабируем картинки так, чтобы их высота была равна высоте строки, и обрезаем их по ширине с центрированием по горизонтали пропорционально их отношению сторон так, чтобы общая ширина строки была равна ширине блока.

```js
var iimgs=document.getElementById("iimgs").childNodes;
var c=document.getElementById("c");
var images=[];
function packimgs(freeH) {
  var padding = 5;
  var divWidth = 510+padding;
  var divHeight = 350+padding;

  var w=0;
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    images[i].aspect=images[i].width/images[i].height;
    w+= images[i].aspect;
  }
  var nrows= Math.round(Math.sqrt(w*divHeight/divWidth));
  // удаление лишних строк от слишком широких картинок
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    if(images[i].aspect > 1.5*w/nrows) nrows-= Math.round(images[i].aspect*nrows/w)-1;
  if(nrows<1) nrows=1;
  var rows= [];
  var rowHeight= divHeight/nrows - padding;
  w= rowHeight*w + padding*images.length;
  for(var j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    rows[j]=[];
    rows[j].space= divWidth;
  }
  j=0;
  var rowWidth=0;
  for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var imgWidth= rowHeight*images[i].aspect+padding;
    if(j<nrows-1 && rows[j].length>0 && Math.abs(rowWidth-w/(nrows-1-j)) < Math.abs(rowWidth-w/(nrows-1-j)+imgWidth*2)) {
      rowWidth=0; j++;
    }
    rows[j].push(images[i]);
    rows[j].space-= imgWidth;
    rowWidth+= imgWidth;
    w-= imgWidth;
  }
  // Подгон высот
  var dhp=0, dhm=0, pn=0;
  for(j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    var rowWidth1= divWidth-padding*rows[j].length
    var rowWidth= rowWidth1-rows[j].space;
    rows[j].height= rowHeight*rowWidth1/rowWidth;
    if(rows[j].height>rowHeight) {
      dhp+= rows[j].height-rowHeight;
      pn++;
    } else dhm+= rowHeight-rows[j].height;
  }
  // второй этап подгона высот (пропустить если не нужно точно соблюдать высоту блока)
  if(!freeH&&dhp!=dhm) for(j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    if(rows[j].height>rowHeight && dhp>dhm)
      rows[j].height= rowHeight + (rows[j].height-rowHeight)*dhm/dhp;
    else if(rows[j].height<rowHeight && dhp<dhm)
      rows[j].height= rowHeight + (rows[j].height-rowHeight)*dhp/dhm;
  }
  // Заполнение блока
  for(j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    var row=document.createElement("DIV");
    row.className='row';
    c.appendChild(row);
    var rowWidth1= divWidth-padding*rows[j].length
    var rowWidth= rowWidth1-rows[j].space;
    var rowHeight1= rows[j].space>0? rowHeight*rowWidth1/rowWidth : rows[j].height;
    for(i=0;i<rows[j].length;i++) {
      var cell=document.createElement("DIV");
      cell.className='cell';
      cell.appendChild(rows[j][i]);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      rows[j][i].style.height= rowHeight1+"px";
      if(rows[j].space>0) {
        cell.style.height= rows[j].height+"px";
        rows[j][i].style.marginTop= (rows[j].height-rowHeight1)/2+"px";
      } else {
        var cwidth= rows[j][i].aspect*rowWidth1*rowHeight/rowWidth;
        cell.style.width= cwidth+"px";
        rows[j][i].style.marginLeft= (cwidth-rows[j][i].width)/2+"px";
      }
    }
  }
}
function chlimit(i) {
  c.innerHTML="";
  packimgs(i.checked);
}
images.loaded=0;
for(i=0;i<iimgs.length;i++) {
  var img= iimgs[i];
  images.push(img);
  img.onload=function() {
    if(images.length==++images.loaded) packimgs();
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
div{margin:0; padding:0; line-height:0;}
.cell{display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class=hidden id=iimgs><img src="http://goo.gl/jD9FJR"><img src="http://goo.gl/A7mxvM"><img src="http://goo.gl/H0K4y0"><img src="http://goo.gl/a8bSmt"><img src="http://goo.gl/oQ3X02"><img src="http://goo.gl/BfO6qj"><img src="http://goo.gl/E6XhJs"><img src="http://goo.gl/adrfhX"><img src="http://goo.gl/OkKx3A"></div><label><input type=checkbox onclick=chlimit(this)>Свободная высота (без обрезки)</label>
<div id="c"></div>
```

**Алгоритм с изменением порядка картинок.**

1. Определяем количество строк как sqrt( сумма отношений сторон всех картинок / отношение сторон блока ), где отношение сторон определяется как ширина делённая на высоту.
2. Определяем *высоту строки* как высоту блока делённую на число строк.
3. Сортируем картинки по соотношению сторон, ставя в начало самые широкие.
4. Распределяем картинки по строкам, помещая очередную картинку в строку с наибольшим свободным пространством, которое определяется как ширина блока минус сумма ширин картинок смасштабированных так, чтобы их высота была равна *высоте строки*.
5. Для строк у которых осталось свободное пространство (до ширины блока) масштабируем картинки так, чтобы занять всю ширину блока, после чего обрезаем их по высоте с центрированием по вертикали.
6. В строках, где нет свободного пространства масштабируем картинки так, чтобы их высота была равна высоте строки, и обрезаем их по ширине с центрированием по горизонтали пропорционально их отношению сторон так, чтобы общая ширина строки была равна ширине блока.

```js
var iimgs=document.getElementById("iimgs").childNodes;
var c=document.getElementById("c");
var images=[];
function packimgs() {
  var divWidth = 510;
  var divHeight = 350;
  var padding = 5;

  var w=0;
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    images[i].aspect=images[i].width/images[i].height;
    w+= images[i].aspect;
  }
  images.sort(function(a,b){return b.aspect-a.aspect;});
  var nrows= Math.round(Math.sqrt(w*divHeight/divWidth));
  // удаление лишних строк от слишком широких картинок
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    if(images[i].aspect > 1.5*w/nrows) nrows-= Math.round(images[i].aspect*nrows/w)-1;
  if(nrows<1) nrows=1;
  var rows= [];
  var rowHeight= (divHeight-padding*(nrows-1))/nrows;
  for(var j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    rows[j]=[]
    rows[j].space= divWidth;
  }
  for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var maxSp=rows[0].space, maxj=0;
    for(var j=1; j<nrows; j++) if(maxSp<rows[j].space) {
      maxSp=rows[j].space;
      maxj=j;
    }
    rows[maxj].space-= rowHeight*images[i].aspect;
    rows[maxj].push(images[i]);
    if(rows[maxj].length>1) rows[maxj].space-= padding;
  }
  for(j=0; j<nrows; j++) {
    var row=document.createElement("DIV");
    row.className='row';
    c.appendChild(row);
    var rowWidth1= divWidth-padding*(rows[j].length-1)
    var rowWidth= rowWidth1-rows[j].space;
    var rowHeight1= rows[j].space>0? rowHeight*rowWidth1/rowWidth : rowHeight;
    for(i=0;i<rows[j].length;i++) {
      var cell=document.createElement("DIV");
      cell.className='cell';
      cell.appendChild(rows[j][i]);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      rows[j][i].height= rowHeight1;
      if(rows[j].space>0) {
        cell.style.height= rowHeight+"px";
        rows[j][i].style.marginTop= (rowHeight-rowHeight1)/2+"px";
      } else {
        var cwidth= rows[j][i].width*rowWidth1/rowWidth;
        cell.style.width= cwidth+"px";
        rows[j][i].style.marginLeft= (cwidth-rows[j][i].width)/2+"px";
      }
    }
  }
}
for(i=0;i<iimgs.length;i++) {
  var img= iimgs[i];
  img.onload=function() {
    images.push(this);
    if(images.length==iimgs.length) packimgs();
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
div{margin:0; padding:0; line-height:0;}
.cell{display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class=hidden id=iimgs><img src="http://goo.gl/jD9FJR"><img src="http://goo.gl/A7mxvM"><img src="http://goo.gl/H0K4y0"><img src="http://goo.gl/a8bSmt"><img src="http://goo.gl/oQ3X02"><img src="http://goo.gl/BfO6qj"><img src="http://goo.gl/E6XhJs"><img src="http://goo.gl/adrfhX"><img src="http://goo.gl/OkKx3A"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: "Сортируем картинки по соотношению сторон, ставя в начало самые широкие" - очередность менять нельзя. Иначе, в вк бы было невозможно постить комиксы и вообще любой материал, смысл которого зависит от последовательности фото.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, тогда вот вам ещё один алгоритм

Comment: круто, спасибо! Как будет время, воспользуюсь вашим вариантом.

Comment: Первый ряд можно сделать немного больше по высоте, чем остальные, только будет еще больше похоже.

Comment: @andreycha, можно изменить подгонку первой строки, но я хотел минимизировать обрезку, поэтому широкая картинка по высоте меньше. Т.е как можно более сохранить соотношение сторон.

Answer (score 11):

Я так и не нашел универсального решения, но опишу как это работает сейчас, может быть это кому-то поможет.

Сейчас я исходя из кол-ва картиночек делю высоту (350 пикселей) на N-ое кол-во строк. Максимум - три, т.к. картиночек может быть всего 10.

Далее, я заполняю строки следующим образом:

1. Считаю для каждой строки суммарное соотношение сторон
2. В строку у которой это значение самое низкое добавляю картинку
3. Если картинки еще есть - пункт 1.

Теперь я задаю ширину картинкам (высота, напомню, это просто 350 / кол-во строк). Делаю я это так:

1. Выбираю очередную строку
2. Достаю очередную картинку
3. Ширина картинки = 510 * (соотношение_сторон_картинки /
   суммарное_соотношение_сторон_картинок_в_сроке)
4. И т.д.

Ну и код, который работает по этому алгоритму:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('imageGrid').controller('imageGridController', function($scope) {

    var divWidth = 510;
    var divHeight = 350;
    var padding = 5;

    var imagesList = $scope.photos;
    angular.forEach(imagesList, function(image, index) {
        image.aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
        image.blockWidth = 0;
        image.blockHeight = 0;
        image.marginBottom = 0;
        image.marginRight = 0;
    }, this);

    var sumOfWidth = function(set) {
        var totalWidth = 0; 
        if (set.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
                totalWidth += set[i].width;
            }
        }
        return totalWidth;
    }

    var sumOfAspectRatio = function(set) {
        var totalAspectRatio = 0; 
        if (set.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
                totalAspectRatio += set[i].aspectRatio;
            }
        }
        return totalAspectRatio;
    }

    var medianAspectRatio = function(set) {
        return this.sumOfAspectRatio(set);
    }

    var linearPartition = function(set) {
        var rows = Math.min(3, Math.ceil(set.length / 3));                

        var rowsArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            rowsArray.push([]);
        }

        for (var l = 0; l < set.length; l++) {
            var rowsAspectRatio = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
                rowsAspectRatio.push(sumOfAspectRatio(rowsArray[i]));
            }
            var minIndex = 0, minValue = Infinity;
            for (var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
                if (rowsAspectRatio[i] < minValue) {
                    minValue = rowsAspectRatio[i];
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }
            rowsArray[minIndex].push(set[l]);
        }

        return rowsArray;
    }

    var setByRows = linearPartition(imagesList);
    var rowsCount = setByRows.length;

    var virtualHeight = Math.floor(divHeight / rowsCount);

    for (var i = 0; i < setByRows.length; i++) {
        var rowAspectRatio = sumOfAspectRatio(setByRows[i]);
        var imagesCount = setByRows[i].length;
        var virtualWidth = imagesCount > 1 ? divWidth - (imagesCount - 1) * padding : divWidth;
        for (var l = 0; l < imagesCount; l++) {
            var image = setByRows[i][l];
            image.blockWidth = Math.floor(virtualWidth / imagesCount);
            image.blockHeight = virtualHeight;
        }

    }

    var resultList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
        var imagesCount = setByRows[i].length;
        for (var l = 0; l < setByRows[i].length; l++) {
            var image = setByRows[i][l];
            image.marginBottom = rowsCount > 1 && i < rowsCount - 1 ? padding : 0;
            image.marginRight = imagesCount > 1 && l < imagesCount - 1 ? padding : 0;
            resultList.push(image);
        }
    }

    $scope.imageList = resultList;
});
```

**Обновление 01.09.2016 16:50**

По просьбе, поясню, что в моем понимании "не универсальное решение". Мой алгоритм не умеет разбивать картинки максимально эффективно.

Вот так отображается три картинки с помощью моего алгоритма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметьте, у всех одинаковая ширина. Первая картинка (красная), обрезается очень, очень сильно, т.к. у нее самая большая ширина из всех картинок.

А вот так эти же картинки отображает ВК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не трудно заметить, что в этом варианте расположения отображается на много большая часть первой картинки (возможно, и всех остальных).

Именно из за этого я и считаю свой алгоритм "не универсальным".

Comment: А скриншоты результата можете добавить в ответ? И в чем именно выражается "неуниверсальность" вашего алгоритма?

Comment: @andreycha, готово, обновил и добавил примеров.

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, но мне ВКонтакте картинки количеством меньше пяти располагает не в два ряда, а в две колонки, причем вне зависимости от соотношения сторон.

Comment: @andreycha, хм, странно. Ни как не могу понять, чем вообще руководствуется ВК'шный алгоритм, а знать хочется. У него, в среднем, все равно лучше получается разбиение, чем у моего.

Comment: Однако ваша программа не соответствует вашему алгоритму. Написано `image.blockWidth = Math.floor(virtualWidth / imagesCount);`  а должно быть наверно `image.blockWidth = Math.floor(virtualWidth*image.aspectRatio/rowAspectRatio);`

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите в сторону вот этих решений, не уверен что это именно то что вам нужно, но, думаю, может помочь в решении вашей проблемы.

[rowGrid.js](https://github.com/brunjo/rowGrid.js)

[Ещё скрипт](http://web.archive.org/web/20160402001801/http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/), но уже с некоторым описанием(ENG)

Comment: Хоть по ссылке и можно найти ответ, необходимо поместить его [ответ] здесь, ведь за внешний ресурс SO не отвечает и он может перестать быть доступным.

Comment: @Other, первая ссылка, думаю, останется актуальной, вторую указал на архивированную версию страницы, все ссылки и файлы тоже в архиве.

Comment: rowGrid.js, на сколько я понимаю, не удовлетворяет изначальному требования вписать картинки в прямоугольник заданного размера (вписывает только по ширине, это проще). И Google+ style image grid тоже.

Comment: Не важно насколько Вы уверены в том, что предоставленные Вами ссылки переживут SO и апокалипсис - правила SO запрещают ответы-ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Все строки кроме первой имеют равную высоту. Сама высота значения не имеет, важны пропорции, поэтому изначально можно взять любую. Для этой высоты перебрать число строк и количество картинок в них. Оставшиеся картинки отправить в первую строку. Вариант с наиболее равномерным расположением выбрать как результат.